# How to update tableview cell constraints in swift

Tags: swift, layout, rotation, constraints, tableview

The constraints are correct when they are in the vertical position(portrait), but when the phone is in the horizontal position(landscape), some of them are updated, some of them are not.

It is clear in the photos

portrait
[image]

landscape
[image]

this is my code :

```
override func willAnimateRotation(to toInterfaceOrientation:      UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.Table_View.reloadData()
        self.Table_View.setNeedsLayout()
        self.Table_View.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sdr", for: indexPath) as! HistoryPagesCell
    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    Cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
    Cell.PageCleanurl.text = HistoryArray[indexPath.row].title
    Cell.PageLasturl.text = HistoryArray[indexPath.row].lasturl
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH-mm"
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: HistoryArray[indexPath.row].date!)
    let str = date
    let replaced = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: ":")
    Cell.Date.text = replaced
    Cell.ViewMain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Cell.ViewMain.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Cell.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    Cell.ViewMain.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Cell.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    Cell.ViewMain.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 43).isActive = true
    Cell.ViewMain.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width - 10).isActive = true
    Cell.Date.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Cell.Date.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Cell.ViewMain.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    Cell.Date.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Cell.ViewMain.rightAnchor, constant: -14).isActive = true
    return Cell
}
```

Comment: Better approach would be use vary for traits form storyboard.

Comment: No i dont want to use storyboard. do you have any answer for this question @NisargShah

Comment: You can try tu update the constraints in will display cell method of table view

Comment: its crashed @NisargShah

Comment: You can debug about crash. Was it due to constraints? Or something else it is?

Comment: i wrote constraints in will display cell method and crashed. and another time i reloaded tableview in will display cell method and tableview was in loop @NisargShah

Comment: Well i said to update constraints, not to add constraints in will display cell. And Don't reload table in that method, as it getting called everytime the new cell is about to display and will freeze the app.

Comment: sorry but i dont understand how should i update constraints in will display cell @NisargShah